# Unity 5.0 running code in function without calling function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a test screen for my unity space shooter game. Where I can change weapons/ship/slots on the ship so testing is more easy.

This is the code:

```
private void CheckValueChange(int value)
    {
        RemoveListItems();

        if (value > 0 && value <= Ship.current.GetComponent<WeaponSystem>().WeaponSlots.Count)
        {
            WeaponSlot slot = Ship.current.GetComponent<WeaponSystem>().WeaponSlots[value - 1];
            if (slot.Weapon)
            {
                FieldInfo[] fields = slot.Weapon.GetType().GetFields();
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if (typeof(ChildStat).IsAssignableFrom(fields[i].FieldType) && fields[i].FieldType != typeof(WeaponDamage))
                    {
                        FieldInfo fInfo = fields[i];

                        ChildStat target = fInfo.GetValue(slot.Weapon) as ChildStat;
                        GameObject go = Instantiate(InputFieldStats, InputContainer);
                        go.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_Text>().text = target.Name;

                        TMP_InputField _InputFieldStats = go.GetComponentInChildren<TMP_InputField>();
                        _InputFieldStats.text = target.BaseValue.ToString();

                        _InputFieldStats.onValueChanged.AddListener((string val) =>
                        {
                            int intVal = Convert.ToInt32(val);
                            target.BaseValue = intVal;
                            fInfo.SetValue(slot.Weapon, target);
                        });

                        //ChildStat dbStat = WeaponDatabase.WeaponList[slot.WeaponIndex].StatValues.Find(stat => stat.Type == target.Type);
                        //dbStat.BaseValue = target.BaseValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working fine but now the variable that I change ingame are directly been updated to the datebase. That happens in this code:

```
_InputFieldStats.onValueChanged.AddListener((string val) =>
       {
          int intVal = Convert.ToInt32(val);
          target.BaseValue = intVal;
          fInfo.SetValue(slot.Weapon, target);
       });
```

As i said this is working fine but I want this to happen on a button click what is the best way I can make this without storing every variable in a private variable. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you use a conditional statement to only update the values if you are not in testing mode? `if(isTesting == false)....`

Comment: @TheSkimek I am already doing that somewhere else the problem is CheckValueChange only runs when a value is changed with a addlistener but the Safe to the database need to happen when I click a button so I can safe my changes. I hope this explains it a little bit better.

Comment: If the saving should only occure when you press a button, there is no other way than keeping them in sepperate variables and call the saving function on button click.When you dont want it to save instant you have to store the information somewhere.

Comment: @TheSkimek I already tought that but I think that looks really messy instaid of having it nice together I just wanted to know if there is a possible way to do it different.

Comment: Maybe do it that way: Make the conditional statement like `if(buttonWasPressed == true) ....[do the saving to database]`  and on the button you can set the `buttonWasPressed` to true.

Comment: @TheSkimek already tried that to but than I need to call that fuction again on a button pressed and that fuctions sets the new inputs that you put in so if I do that and I change value's and press the button is starts from the top so it first gets the old inputs and than put those in the datebase so nothing changes

Comment: Ok last try from me:
`private void CheckValueChange(int value, bool update)` -> Put this function as `CheckValueChange(0,true)` on the button and as `CheckValueChange([newValue],false)` wherever this function has to be called else. Then you can pull the saving part to `if(update == true){ _InputFieldStats.onValueChanged.AddListener((string val)...` and the rest into an `else{ [do the other stuff]}`

Comment: @TheSkimek That is a really smart plan let me try that out I will update you!

Comment: @TheSkimek I finally fixed it dont ask me how but it works haha Thanks for the help!